# What gets logged to the console when the user clicks on “Button 4” and why?

Tags: object, variables, scope, executioncontext

Consider the following code snippet:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Button ' + i));
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(){ console.log(i);});
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no matter what button the user clicks, the number `5` will always be logged to the console.

This is because, at the point that the `onclick` method is invoked (for any of the buttons), the for loop has already completed and the variable `i` already has a value of `5`.

> Bonus points, you can read more about **execution contexts**, **variable objects**, **activation objects**, and the **internal “scope” property**, this contributes to the closure behavior.And you will understand the magic here.